# Me captura valor nulo cuando realizo un select a la base de datos

Tags: java, java-ee

Bueno el problema consiste: no me captura el valor que existe en la base de datos especialmente en campo `codsubmenu`, solo me está capturando valores nulos. Les dejo el código.

```
public class Menu implements Serializable{

    private int idMenu;
    private Menu codsubmenu;

    public int getIdMenu() {
        return idMenu;
    }

    public void setIdMenu(int idMenu) {
        this.idMenu = idMenu;
    }

    public Menu getCodsubmenu() {
        return codsubmenu;
    }

    public void setCodsubmenu(Menu codsubmenu) {
        this.codsubmenu = codsubmenu;
    }      

    while(rs.next()){
        Menu menu=new Menu(); 
        menu.setIdMenu(rs.getInt("idMenu")); //en esta línea si me captura el id del menu

        // me captura null 
        menu.setCodsubmenu(menu.getCodsubmenu());
    }  
}
```

Sin embargo, al cambiar la última línea por:

```
menu.setCodsubmenu(rs.getInt("codsubmenu"));
```

Me subraya el error de esta forma

```
incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Menu**
```

Comment: No logro comprender tu pregunta. Ayudaría su fueras más específico, arreglaras la identación del código y mejoraras tu redacción.

Comment: el método `menu.setCodsubmenu` no figura en tu código. Así mismo tampoco figura el tipo de `rs`. Poco se puede hacer entonces por resolver tu duda. En cualquier caso hacer `menu.set(menu.get())`, en referencia a tu comentario de *me captura null*, no va modificar absolutamente nada.

Comment: En ningun lugar le estas asignando un valor a codsubmenu, entonces intentas acceder a el, aun es null.

Answer (score 1):

Aunque creo que faltan datos quizas esto le ayude:

usted dice que le captura null, y eso es porque usted hace `menu.getCodsubmenu()`,

```
    // me captura null 
    menu.setCodsubmenu(menu.getCodsubmenu());
```

y este devuelve null porque

```
public Menu getCodsubmenu() {
    return codsubmenu;
}

public void setCodsubmenu(Menu codsubmenu) {
    this.codsubmenu = codsubmenu;
}
```

esta asignado y devolviendo el mismo objeto que no ha sido inicializado ni asignado a otro que estubiera inicializado previamente:

```
private Menu codsubmenu;

getCodsubmenu() -> devuelve codesubmenu y menu.setCodsubmenu asigna el mismo objeto, al mismo objeto que no esta inicializado, quizas quiera mirar eso.
```

---

este mensaje `types: int cannot be converted to Menu**` es por esto incompatible

```
public void setCodsubmenu(Menu codsubmenu) {
    this.codsubmenu = codsubmenu;
}
```

este metodo espera un `Menu` pero si su nombre en este metodo `menu.setCodsubmenu(rs.getInt("codsubmenu"));` sigue alguna logica `getInt` puede que este devolviendo un Int de ahi el error, es que no puede asignar un entero en `setCodsubmenu` pues espera un `Menu` para asignarlo a `codsubmenu` que es del tipo `Menu`;

---

Answer (score 0):

Tienes lo siguiente: `Menu codsubmenu`. Tu código de submenu es un objeto de la clase `Menu`. Actualmente, lo estás seteando de la siguiente manera:

```
menu.setCodsubmenu(menu.getCodsubmenu());
```

Pero cuando tu creas una instancia de `Menu`, el campo `codsubmenu` puesto que no tiene ninguna inicialización (al menos por lo que presentas en tu código) tendrá como valor por defecto `null`, por ende esa línea de código no tienen ningún significado.

Ahora, cuando intentas hacer esto:

```
menu.setCodsubmenu(rs.getInt("codsubmenu"));
```

El error de compilación es explícito: estás intentando asignar a una variable de tipo `Menu` el valor de un `int`.

Quizás tu problema sea de orden al momento de leer los datos. Puesto que no explicas bien tu problema de fondo, yo creo que primero deberías leer todos los datos, almacenar `Menu` por `Menu` en un contenedor como una lista o un mapa y luego agruparlos de la manera en que deseas. Por cierto, como nota personal, quizás también tengas un problema de diseño en tu modelo de datos, porque un menú no debería tener el id de un menú hijo, sino más bien debería tener el id del menú padre, y el único menú que no tenga id de padre es la raíz de todos los menús.